# Chrome blocking ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome

All,
I have the following ajax request that works fine in IE (I know right??) but when I try to use the same code in Chrome I get the following error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://ahmwpsds01:1234/NASAService/GetNASAUser.asmx/GetUserByName. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://ahmwpsds01' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500.

Ajax Request

```
function getNASAProfile(user) {
    var dfd = new $.Deferred(function () {
        $.support.cors = true;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://ahmwpsds01:1234/NASAService/GetNASAUser.asmx/GetUserByName",
            data: "{userName: '" + UserProfile.Name + "'}",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            accept: "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
        })
        .done(function (data) {
            //alert('Call Succeeded');
            dfd.resolve(data.d);
        })
        .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert('Call Failed\n\n' + jqXHR.statusText + "\n\n" + errorThrown + "\n\n" + textStatus);
        });
    });
    return dfd.promise();
}
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Yup, your typical CORS error. IE is incorrectly allowing it, or not sending an OPTIONS preflight request that should be required with the given request.

Comment: It's exactly what it says it is.  The url you are requesting needs a Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Comment: No I don't think so since I am sending $.support.cors and it works in IE.

Comment: @JDSanders it's clearly a CORS error, read the error message. Research what CORS means and how it works. Your server isn't responding to the CORS request in such a way that would allow the browser to make the request successfully.

Comment: Also, the JSON you are posting is invalid, fyi. your server might not care though.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** Didn't notice that you want to make a POST request. You should consider using a backend method for your case

You are trying to access a resource that is on a different server. For security reasons, you are not allowed to do that with a simple AJAX call.

To work out the problem, you can use JSONP. The simple way to do it is to add `?callback=?` to the URL. Plus, the server response must be wrapped in a function definition. You might want to use a proxy like [YQL](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql) to convert the response to JSONP.

More information on this link :
http://json-jsonp-tutorial.craic.com/index.html

Comment: Then show him the solution...

Comment: I edited my answer, sorry for not providing enough details the first time

Comment: Keep in mind that it is **impossible** to POST with the jsonp datatype.